# What is the fastest way to access a node/edge in igraph (python)

Tags: python, performance, networkx, igraph

I'm currently trying to change the library of a python program from networkx to igraph because igraph seems faster.
But I'm actually seeing a increase in execution time, especially when accessing node and edges in graphs. The fastest way (I'm aware of) to do this is using the vertices sequence and the index of a node like this : graph.vs[index]. And it's still slower than networkx's access.
So I made a quick benchmark and I got this results:

|  | igraph | networkx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node access | 1,08E-04 | 5,08E-05 |
| Edge access | 3,23E-04 | 1,83E-04 |

Here's the code for the "benchmark"

```
import networkx as nx
import igraph as ig
import time

f = open("results.csv", "w+")

#Create the same networkx and igraph graph and adding some edges
graph_nx = nx.generators.gn_graph(1000)
graph_nx.add_edges_from([(500,999,{'test' : '3'})])
graph_ig = ig.Graph.from_networkx(graph_nx)


#time to access a node, networkx
for i in range(0, 100):
    sec = time.time()
    graph_nx.nodes[500]
    print(time.time() - sec, file=f, end='')
    if (i != 100):
        print(",", file=f, end='')
print(file=f)

#time to access a node by index, igraph
for i in range(0, 100):
    sec = time.time()
    graph_ig.vs[500]
    print(time.time() - sec, file=f, end='')
    if (i != 100):
        print(",", file=f, end='')
print(file=f)

#time to access an edge, networkx
for i in range(0, 100):
    sec = time.time()
    graph_nx[500][999]
    print(time.time() - sec, file=f, end='')
    if (i != 100):
        print(",", file=f, end='')
print(file=f)

#time to access an edge by index, igraph
for i in range(0, 100):
    sec = time.time()
    graph_ig.es[500]
    print(time.time() - sec, file=f, end='')
    if (i != 100):
        print(",", file=f, end='')
print(file=f)
```

So what's the fastest way to access edges/nodes in igraph ?

Comment: "Accessing an edge" is not a well-defined concept, and it's not comparable between libraries. One normally does this to achieve another goal. What is that goal, what is it that you are actually trying to do? igraph uses integer IDs to refer to vertices and edges. In order to do something with the 10th edge, you would not normally execute `g.es[10]` with igraph. You only need `10`. If you give a more realistic example of an operation that is slower with igraph than NetworkX, we may be able to give advice. But the benchmark you show here is not practically meaningful.

Comment: I already have the integer ids of the edge and vertices, because I made an index of them when I'm building my graph, I do not need to worry about them changing because I never delete/add vertice and edges after that.
So my question is, is there a faster way to access edges and vertices than g.es[index] and g.vs[index] in igraph ?

Comment: It's not possible to give any useful answer here unless you show what you are actually trying to do. You are assuming:(1) that `g.es[index]` is necessary for your task (2) that the performance of `g.es[index]` is your bottleneck. Both of these assumptions are likely incorrect, but it's impossible to tell without knowing what you are actually doing.

Comment: I did a profiling on my code using [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) and found that (.vs and .es) are the bottleneck. As for accessing the nodes, I'm provided with the id of each in this loop:

`for i in range(len(paths)-1):`
              `n1_id, n2_id = paths[i], paths[i+1]`
              #accessing
              n1 = nindex[n1_id]
              n2 = nindex[n2_id]
'''

Comment: sorry my code is messy and wrong here it is: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3Yi0qYhq)

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. Why do you believe you need `g.es[index]`? What do you want to do with that object that you cannot do with `index` alone?

Comment: Sorry I didn't undertand, I need the object because it has attributes I need in it.

Comment: Get the attribute vector first, then index into it. `g.es['myattr'][index]`. This should be faster.

Comment: The main cause of the difference is probably that `Vertex` and `Edge` objects in igraph (the ones that you get from indexing into `g.vs` and `g.es`) spring into existence _when_ needed. Running `g.vs[x]` is actually _creating_ a `Vertex` object on-the-fly because igraph's C graph representation does not have an object for each individual vertex. Most likely NetworkX already has the vertex and edge objects so indexing into the vertex or edge collection is simply an array lookup.

Comment: Ohh ok I see then, I probably need to store the attribute in my own data struct.